# MongoDB Database data getting deleted while using Docker on Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, digital-ocean

I am hosting my website http://apgiiit.com/ on Digital Ocean cloud using docker containers. Site is build using Express and MongoDB. But, it seems when I run docker-compose down command all of my database data is getting wiped out somehow. I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my docker-compose and Docker files for the project.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: express_blog
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:5000'
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb:/data/db/
volumes:
  mongodb:
    external: true
```

Here's the other docker file used to run express.

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I am using external volumes for storing mongodb data. I've created another volume using docker volume command and using that volume in the docker-compose file. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: did you check ./mongodb? after writing to the container are there any data?

Comment: I just logged in and retrieved the 'mongodb' folder which I created inside the project and mapping to the docker container for storing mongodb data. 'mongodb' folder does seem to have data. I haven't ever imported data into mongodb from any external source. But yes, the folder isn't empty and does seem to have something. What am I doing wrong here ? Why the data is not being persistent ?

Comment: u r using droplet or app service? You said you haven't imported any data, but you mention the data is not persistent. Means you have imported the data. Can you clarify?

Comment: Well, I used Filezilla to login into my Digital Ocean server and retrieved the 'mongodb' folder from the project folder. It's size is 338 MB. but when I run docker-compose down, it seems it is deleting the volume data. It seems data inside the mongo container is getting reset and all my application data is wiped out. I have no idea what is happening, what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: after you run the container , go inside the container and see the content. If you can use absolute path for the volume etc `$(pwd)/mongodb:/database/db` and see if it helps. If you mount correctly, and the data is in /mongodb then the data will load from /mongodb

Comment: I really need a solution for this issue. I'm not on Digital Ocean but the exact same thing happens to me.

Comment: I've seen multiple people complaining this, a now own a personal VPS on another platform and this issue is not there. Seems to be something exclusive to Digital Ocean Droplets.

Answer (score 0):

you must use docker-compose stop because docker-compose down remove containers, networks, volumes and images.

documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_down/